# Dartium debugger stops working if server is used

Tags: debugging, dart, dartium

After updating dartium to 0.4.7.1_r21548 (same for 0.5.0.1_r21823) i am unable to debug anymore. I have written a small test and discovered that the breakpoints are hit if i call the file direct. But if i use a server and call the page (`http://localhost:8080/test.html`) the dart code works perfectly, but the breakpoints are missed!

I am not debugging with dart-editor. Only dartium is used.

Here is my test:

test.dart

```dart
void main() {
  print("hallo");
}
```

test.html

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  <script type="application/dart" src="test.dart"></script>
</head>
<body>
Hallo
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in the Dart Editor that a bunch of people have run into.

We're currently looking into it.

You can follow the bug about this, here: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=10215